# undefined method `ARGV' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, argv

arguments = ARGV[0] if Gem.win_platform? && ARGV[0] arguments = arguments.encode('UTF-8') end

if arguments == 'Fool' puts "You fool" else puts "Hello, my dear" end

Comment: Do you have any spaces after `ARGV`? For example `ARGV [0]`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.